# Array declaration: C Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I am trying to write an array (2x20000) on C. The test code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>  

double test( int smod )
{
//
// test subroutine
//
double  vect_fma[2][20000];
int i;

// write on file //
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
///////////////////

   for( i = 1; i < 20001; i = i + 1 ){     
    // allocate the vector for the fma analysis
    vect_fma[1][i] = i*smod;
    vect_fma[2][i] = i*smod;
    if ( i%smod == 0 ) 
    fprintf(f, "%f %f %f  \n", 1.0*i, vect_fma[1][i],vect_fma[2][i] );   
}    
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}  


int smod;
void main()
{  
  smod  = 10; // every 10 print the output 
    test(smod);    // call the function  
}
```

I compiled the code with `gcc test.c -lm -o test` and I received `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` .

As far as I am new on C, I understand that "[the compiler tries to store it on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098917/3d-array-declaration-causes-segmentation-fault)" and a solution could be the one presented in the linked page....but that solution looks quite weird (and complex to understand) if compared with more simple fortran declaration of array `real(8), dimension(n:m) :: vect_fma` which I can put in a subroutine or in a function without problems. 
Is maybe that the declaration I wrote in the code is similar to the fortran `real(8), dimension(n,m),allocatable :: vect_fma` one ?

So the question is, it exist a simpler way in C to declare an array inside a function ?
Many thanks to everybody.

Comment: Probably too big for the stack - use the heap instead

Comment: @EdHeal something like that `2d_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);` ?

Comment: Did you receive the segmentation fault during compilation (which is what your answer implies) or during execution?

Comment: C arrays are *always* 0-based indexes, not 1-based indexes. `vect_fma[2]` is outside the bounds of the array, and so is `vect_fma[1][i]` when `i == 20000`.

Comment: @CorbinMc during execution

Comment: @DarkFalcon many thanks even changing it `vect_fma[0][i] = ...` and `vect_fma[1][i] = ...` the problem still persist.

Comment: You do not need the cast - also I thought you want doubles

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro: Did you fix the range of `i` too?

Comment: DId `fopen()` really succeeded? `fprintf()`ing to `NULL` is not a good idea ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have out of bounds access in multiple places, which is *undefined behaviour*.
In C, an array index ranges from `0` to `N-1`, not from `1` to `N`. That means, rewriting the loop part to:

```
   for( i = 0; i < 20000; i = i + 1 ){     
    // allocate the vector for the fma analysis
    vect_fma[0][i] = i*smod;
    vect_fma[1][i] = i*smod;
    if ( i%smod == 0 ) 
       fprintf(f, "%f %f %f  \n", 1.0*i, vect_fma[0][i],vect_fma[1][i] );   
}
```

It's possible 2x20000 doubles might be too big for the stack size on your system, you'd better off fixing the undefined behaviours first
and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: thanks for your answer it was correct about the integers and thanks for the example posted. I mixed up with fortran which start from 1 to 20000 which means I have 20000 elements, instead in C I have to start from 0 to 20000 .

Comment: 0 to 19999 not 20000, because is `< 20000`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `for` loop. You should begin with an iteration where `i=0` and end with an iteration where `i=19999`. Your code begins with an iteration where `i=1` and ends with an iteration where `i=20000`.

The problem is that that there is no 20000th element of your array, only a 19999th (zero indexed). When you access the the 20000th element your accessing system memory that was never allocated for your program which is causing a segmentation fault.

Fix your for loop and you should be good.